# Fans not running in Ubuntu 20.04 Lenovo Legion Y540

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, fan, overheating

I have started to use Lenovo legion Y540 in dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. And I am having issue with my fan speed.

I am unable to see what the current fan speed is and the fan seems to run idle and very quite, I feel that the fan is not running at all.

I tried to find a shortcut to increase the fan, but failed to find any solution. I simply don't know what to do next, may anyone please help me out? It's not working even when pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>.

Comment: There's no shortcut to "run the fan". Fans are typically controlled by the firmware (UEFI or old BIOS) and on-demand, no user or even OS input/control required. So, do you actually have a problem or just a feeling that the fans should be working harder?